# Changing font color without using color style

Tags: css

I'm currently using a content management system that is automatically stripping any `style="color:white;"` inline css, but I need to change the font color of a certain element to white. Is there any trick I can use that can make it appear as if the font is white, without using `color:white`? (note the white here could have been #fff, rgb(0,0,0) ect)

Note:

I cannot define a css class because `<style>` tags are deleted completely, and any inline color definition is changed to "color: ;". I was hoping for a solution where I can use something like webkit stroke to make something with black font appear white, or something tricky like that

Comment: Can you use color: #fff; ?

Comment: Try to assign it a CSS class and define color inside it

Comment: What kind of CMS would do that?

Comment: You could try to make it more specific like `[container class] [element]` so if the container had a class of "content" you could make it `.content p { color: #fff !important}`. Yeah add the important to make sure that it kicks in.

Comment: By the way, your CMS is not stripping the white, the stylesheet in theme is overriding it. If you are using WordPress, create a child theme.

Comment: Its reddot, and my inline css would normally override the cms style theme because it gets loaded afterwards, and unfortunately these solutions did not work

Comment: @TheoretiCAL , that is odd. Can you post a link to your website.

Comment: kinda didn't get the point

Comment: `style` tag is deleted, but can you add `link` or `script` tags? I guess the real question is: what tags can you use? would the CMS allow a `<white>` tag that you can define on the CSS as `white{color:white}`? (although I understand that it wouldn't be valid HTML anymore)

Answer (score 3):

`color: #ffffff;` is the hex of white, also if they check against that try `color: rgb(0, 0, 0);` or `rgba(0,0,0,1);`

or better yet use CSS classes:

HTML

```
<div class="white"></div>
```

CSS

```
.white {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the CMS actually removes a `style` attribute (though this may be a misinterpretation), then set `class=white` on the element and add the following CSS code to an external style sheet being used or in a `style` element:

```
.white { color: white }
```

If this is not possible, then use `font` markup, e.g. instead of `<span style="color:white;">foo</span>` use

```
<span color=white>foo</font>
```